# Binding Listview Items to multiple Models

Tags: xamarin, data-binding

I have a List view with a label and an entry. I set the item source of ListView to SQL table in codebehind. My label will have its text from this SQL, but I want to save my `Entry.Text` to a new model (binding to another model that is not related to listview itemsource)...

HOW TO DO IT??

The SQL stores names.

Here is my xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="Mlist" Grid.Row="3" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Padding="5" BackgroundColor="White" RowSpacing="40">
                    <Label x:Name="label" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding name}" />
                    <Entry x:Name="money" Placeholder="type the income" Text={ *** Binding to another model that is not related to listview itemsource}
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
Mlist.itemsource = conn.Table<peaople>().ToList();
```

Comment: create a new model that combines both fields - this is essentially what a ViewModel is

Answer (score 0):

Move the code which manipulate data into the viewmodel ,make `ViewModel` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` ,  and set the viewmodel as the `BindingContext` in code behind.

#### ViewModel

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   List<People> list;
   public List<People> List { 
       get
       {
           return list;
       }
       set
       {
           list = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged();
       } 
   }

   private string money;        
   public string Money   //add Money property directly in viewmodel
   {
       get { return money; }
       set
       {
           money = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged();
       }
   }

   public ViewModel()
   {
       List = conn.Table<People>().ToList(); 
   } 
}
```

#### Page(code behind)

```cs
viewModel = new ViewModel();
this.BindingContext = viewModel;
```

#### Xaml

Name current page as `Self` , and redirect the binding path on `Entry.Text`.

```cs
             x:Class="FormsApp.Views.Page1"
             x:Name="Self"
             >

    <ListView x:Name="Mlist" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" RowHeight="100" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout  >
                        <Label x:Name="label" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Entry x:Name="money" Placeholder="type the income" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference Self}, Path=BindingContext.Money}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

#### Screen shot

All the Entry share the data `Money` .

[image]

Comment: this doesn't address the question OP asked at all

Comment: Thank you all i will try to put all in a viewmodel and will send the results.

Comment: That's fine , if you have any question please let me know.

Comment: thank you very much. it is not working man. when I'm trying to bind Entry.text nothing saves in model. because money is not in the list. I cant relate these 2 in 1 class of viewmodel.

Comment: You can use `{x:Reference}` to bind on another property not in the list . Please check my update .

Comment: why cant I  use {x:refrence moneyModel}, path=money}?? @ColeX

Comment: `moneyModel.money` is invalid binding path. Did you try my code ?